# How does COUNT work with multiple streams in XREADGROUP?

Tags: redis, consumer, redis-streams

I want to use the Redis [`XREADGROUP`](https://redis.io/commands/xreadgroup) command to consume messages from *multiple* Redis streams. What does the `COUNT` parameter mean in such cases (i.e. is it the total number of messages, or a number of messages per stream)? Also, is it possible to read exactly one message with this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNT` is the maximum number of elements per stream. The `XREADGROUP` command is a special version of the `XREAD` command with support for consumer groups. So the documentation for [`XREAD`](https://redis.io/commands/xread) applies.

You can set COUNT as 1, then you'll get up to 1 element per stream in the command.

If you don't set `COUNT`, you get all messages available per stream.

Comment: Also, `COUNT` is ignored if you're in a `BLOCK`

Comment: @Itamar Haber: Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: `BLOCK` is entered into only of the streams are empty. Once there's a single incoming message, the blocking is released with that message... so `COUNT` is always 1 in that case.